# How to get Plain text from EditText and not "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{e67388"

Tags: android

How to get text from EditText widget that user actually typed, I am keep getting this text in my database: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{e67388".

I am getting this response:
Register Response: {"error":false,"uid":"56807035b02430.42354570","user":{"first_name":"Tom","last_name":"Black","email":"tom@tom.com",**"pets_race":"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{e67388"**,**"pets_name":"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{2c8d71"**,"created_at":"2015-12-28","updated_at":null}}

I am using wamp server. Here are all files that are have anything to do with with DB:

RegistrationPage.java

```
package com.adicili.petdetective;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.adicili.petdetective.R;
import com.adicili.petdetective.AppConfig;
import com.adicili.petdetective.AppController;
import com.adicili.petdetective.SQLiteHandler;
import com.adicili.petdetective.SessionManager;

public class RegistrationPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = RegistrationPage.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnRegister;
private Button btnBackToLogin;
private EditText inputFirstName;
private EditText inputLastName;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private EditText inputPetsRace;
private EditText inputPetsName;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_page);

    inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFirstName);
    inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLastName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmailReg);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPasswordReg);
    inputPetsRace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPetsRace);
    inputPetsName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPetsName);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnBackToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBackToLogin);

    //PRogress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    //Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    //SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    //Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()){
        //User is alreday logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationPage.this, HomePage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            String first_name = inputFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
            String last_name = inputLastName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.toString().trim();
            String pets_race = inputPetsRace.toString();
            String pets_name = inputPetsName.toString();

            if(!first_name.isEmpty() && !last_name.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty()){
                registerUser(first_name, last_name, email, password, pets_race, pets_name);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    //Link to Login Screen
    btnBackToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

/*
*Function to store user in MySQL dataase will post params to            *register url
 */

private void registerUser(final String first_name, final String last_name, final String email, final String password, final String pets_race, final String pets_name){
    //Tag used to cacel request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    //User successfully stored in DB
                    //Now store user in SQL lite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String first_name = user.getString("first_name");
                    String last_name = user.getString("last_name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String pets_race = user.getString("pets_race");
                    String pets_name = user.getString("pets_name");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                    //Inserting row in DB
                    db.addUser(first_name, last_name, email, pets_race, pets_name, uid, created_at);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationPage.this, LoginPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try Login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //Error occured in registration. Get the error
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            //Postinf params to register url
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("first_name", first_name);
            params.put("last_name", last_name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("pets_race", pets_race);
            params.put("pets_name", pets_name);

            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
private void showDialog(){
    if(!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog(){
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

SQLiteHandler.java

```
package com.adicili.petdetective;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

//All static variables
//Database Version
private static final  int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

//Login table name
private  static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

//Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_PETS_RACE = "pets_race";
private static final String KEY_PETS_NAME = "pets_name";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public SQLiteHandler(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

//Creating tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "Create table " + TABLE_USER + "(" + KEY_ID + " Integer primary key," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " Text," + KEY_LAST_NAME + " Text," + KEY_EMAIL + " Text unique," + KEY_PETS_RACE + " Text," + KEY_PETS_NAME + " Text," + KEY_UID + " Text," + KEY_CREATED_AT + " Text" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "DATABASE tables created");
}
//Upgrading daabase
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    //Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("Drop table if exists " + TABLE_USER);

    //Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 */
public void addUser(String first_name, String last_name, String email, String pets_race, String pets_name, String uid, String created_at){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, first_name);
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, last_name);
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    values.put(KEY_PETS_RACE, pets_race);
    values.put(KEY_PETS_NAME, pets_name);
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid);
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at);

    //Inserting row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER,null,values);
    db.close();//closing db connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);

}

/*
*Getting user data from database
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "Select * from " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        user.put("first_name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("last_name", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("pets_race", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("pets_name", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(7));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    //return user
    Log.d(TAG,"Fetching user from sqlite: " +user.toString());
    return user;
}

/*
*Re create database Delete all tables and create them again
 */
public void deleteUsers(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //Delete all rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER,null,null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG,"Delete all user info from sqlite");
}

}
```

register.php

```
<?php

require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

//json response array
$responce = array("error" => FALSE);

if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

//recieving the post params
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pets_race = $_POST['pets_race'];
$pets_name = $_POST['pets_name'];

//check if user already existrd with same email
if($db->isUserExisted($email)){
    //user already existed
    $responce["error"] = TRUE;
    $responce["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
    echo json_encode($responce);
}else{
    //create new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($first_name,$last_name,$email,$password,$pets_race,$pets_name);
    if($user){
        //user stored successfully
        $responce["error"] = FALSE;
        $responce["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $responce["user"]["first_name"] = $user["first_name"];
        $responce["user"]["last_name"] = $user["last_name"];
        $responce["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $responce["user"]["pets_race"] = $user["pets_race"];
        $responce["user"]["pets_name"] = $user["pets_name"];
        $responce["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $responce["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($responce);
    }else{
        //user failed to store
        $responce["error"] = TRUE;
        $responce["error_msg"]= "Unknown error occured in registration!";
        echo json_encode($responce);
    }
}
}else{
$responce["error"]=TRUE;
$responce["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (First Name, Last Name, email or password) is missing!";
echo json_encode($responce);

}
?>
```

storeUser method from DB_Functions.php:

```
<?php
class DB_Functions{
private $conn;

//constructor
Function __construct(){
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    //connecting to db
    $db = new Db_connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
//destructir
function __destruct(){

}

/**
*Storing new user
*returns user details
*/
public function storeUser($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $pets_race, $pets_name){
    $uuid = uniqid('',true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"];
    $salt = $hash["salt"];


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("Insert INTO users(unique_id, first_name, last_name, email, encrypted_password, pets_race,pets_name,salt,created_at) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$uuid,$first_name,$last_name, $email,$encrypted_password,$pets_race,$pets_name,$salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    //check for successfull store
    if($result){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from users where email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To retrieve plain text from an `EditText`, use `getText().toString()`, not just `toString()`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!